# Converting character to numeric in R

Tags: r

I Have dataset like below which I am trying to convert column "Installs" to numeric, my codes are like below:

[Original Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL5po.png)

My Codes:-

```
Data$Installs<-substr(Data$Installs,1,nchar(Data$Installs)-1)
Data$Installs<-gsub(",","",gsub("\\s+","",Data$Installs))
Data$Installs<-as.numeric(Data$Installs)
```

after the code I get below

[This is the result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6atZY.png)
Any help?

Comment: Please don't link images of data or results.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you need only to remove commas and a possible trailing plus sign.  So, the following should work:

```
Data$Installs <- as.numeric(gsub("[+,]", "", Data$Installs))
```

You might want to create a new column though and keep the original one.

Comment: Thanks for the codes but it still gives same output

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by this.  My code should work assuming your install column be text.

Comment: what I meant to say is everything works fine till (your code and my code to remove + and ,), however I start loosing data as soon as I try to convert the column from character to numeric using as.numeric()

Comment: I tried with this also Data2$Installs<-as.numeric(trimws(Data2$Installs)), does not work

Comment: when I use "Data2$Installs<-lapply(Data2$Installs,function(x) as.numeric(x))", few gets converted to numeric value correctly but few do not

Comment: Edit your question and show clear input data, along with both the current and expected output.  Do **not** paste links or include images.